# Alarm's setRepeating first trigger issue

Tags: android, alarmmanager

Can someone please explain why the following code is working (ie. first alarm fires with 20 second delay):

```
Calendar cal =  Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add (Calendar.SECOND,20);
am = (AlarmManager)this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 20000, PendingIntent pi);
```

while the following is NOT (ie. first alarm fires instantly):

```
am = (AlarmManager)this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 20000, 20000, PendingIntent pi);
```

Answer (score 0):

`SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()`[1] returns the number of milliseconds since boot.

`cal.getTimeInMillis()`[2] returns number of millisecond since UNIX Epoch (1970/01/01)... based on your code.

The first code block is actually scheduling an alarm for 20 seconds in the future.

The second code block is actually scheduling an alarm in the distant past (unless you booted up your phone 1st Jan 1970!) and the time for the alarm to be run has already passed. The alarm hasn't run yet though, so it runs it now that it's flagged the time as elapsed.

[1] http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html#elapsedRealtime()

[2] http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#getTimeInMillis()